# Get an error when calling a function from a different include_once file?

Tags: php, function, php-7, anonymous-class, include-once

I have a structure like so:

> `main.php`
>
> > include_once `func1.php`
> >
> > include_once `func2.php`

These two files are `include`'d inside `main.php`.

I get the error below when I call a `function switchboard()` from `func1.php` inside `finc2.php`.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function switchboard() on null in func2.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 main.php(60): decode_func('{"auth":"...)
#1 {main} thrown in func2.php on line 16
```

**Line 16** is where I call the function from `func1.php` inside `func2.php` —
`switchboard() {}`. Is there a way to fix this besides `include`ing `func1.php` inside `func2.php`?

---

**func2.php**

```
 function decode($var) {

     if() {return $var;} 
     else { $erm->switchboard('101', $var); }   
 }
```

**func1.php**

```
 $erm = new CLASS() {

   function switchboard($id, $var) {

     if() {}
     else {}
   }

 }
```

Comment: If this isn't legacy code, consider using a framework or at least composer to manage your application in a more modern way.

Comment: I have setup `Exception`s inside `main.php`...that are being called in `func1.php`. Will they still work if `func1.php`  is inside `func2.php`? @HankyPanky

Comment: @HankyPanky And for the sake of expandability in the future, what if there is a third file say `func3.php`...included in main. Is there a more elegant and versatile way do organizing this?

Comment: The function is defined, but the object that you're trying to call it from isn't an object. Show your code.

Comment: Follow @aynbar's advice that makes sense

Comment: This has nothing to do with including files.. PHP obviously complains you're trying to call the function on a null object. Also, if you want a concrete solution, you should post the shortest REAL code that causes you problems.

Comment: @walther Simplified version of my code was added. Please take a look.

Comment: @aynber Simplified version of my code was added. Please take a look.

Comment: I've never seen a class defined that way, but apparently it's semi-valid. Try taking the parenthesis off of your declaration: `$erm = new CLASS {`

Comment: @aynber Its a new way to define anonymous classes in php 7. Just did. Get the same error though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be because you use `$erm` in the function `decode()`, yet it is not included in the function's scope (let's keep in mind that contrarily to javascript, php functions do not inherit their surrounding scope)

You can declare `decode` as an anonymous function and take advantage of `use` to inject `$erm` inside it, or make `$erm` an argument of decode.

- Anonymous function

Just `use` $erm to make sure to include it inside decode's scope:

```
$decode = function ($var) use ($erm) {
    if() { return $var; } 
    else { $erm->switchboard('101', $var); }   
};
```

- Parameter

Pass `$erm` like any other parameter.

```
function decode ($var, $erm) {
    if(false) { return $var; } 
    else { $erm->switchboard('101', $var); }   
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error `syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'`...what is causing this?

Comment: In the func2.php file I have it as `function decode($var1, $var2) use ($erm)`. Same as your code above. With parenthesis. Says the error is on the line where I open the function.

Comment: Doesn't even get to the line where I call the external function. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you actually paste that non working code on [eval.in](https://eval.in) so that we can reproduce the error? the use keyword is a known php feature, it works. without the specific code, it's only jabs in the dark ;)

Comment: Just did. Doesn't show any errors. But maybe the fact that the code is split between multiple files cannot be accounted for on eval.in. When I disable this function everything works well with my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139298/discussion-between-felix-gagnon-grenier-and-borsn).